# Command Prompt Script command "cd"

Tags: windows, windows-7, cmd

Ok so I was making my own little command prompt for my own personal use and I have been fighting to make it work for the past 2 hours. Here is what I have done:

```
@echo off
set /p labnum="Enter Lab Numnber:"
set labdir=C:\Users\BLAHBLAHBLAH\Dir\Lab-
set labdir2="%labdir%%labnum%"
cd labdir2
:cmd
set /p cmd=">"
%cmd%
cls
goto cmd
```

I basically want to be able to change the path before each "session" But every time the cd labdir2 command is executed, my computer whines, "The system cannot find the path specified." And I know FOR SURE that the directory exists! I have pasted the text straight from windows explorer. Any and all help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here:

```
cd labdir2
```

that changes to a directory called `labdir2`, but you want to change to a directory indicated by the contents of the variable:

```
cd %labdir2%
```

to make sure you can cope with special characters I'd enclose it with double quotes:

```
cd "%labdir2%"
```

You might even want to include the /d swith with the `cd` command to make sure that you also change the current drive. So the final version should be:

```
cd /d "%labdir2%"
```

Comment: +1 Quoting is certainly a good practice here, so I wouldn't disagree with your suggestion. For completeness, however, note that (for the better or worse ;-) `cd` can cope with spaces in the directory name without quoting the name. E.g. `mkdir "a dir"` and then `cd a dir` changes to `a dir` (also see `help cd`). Quoting is of course required for other special characters (like you said), like `^`.

Comment: In my experience, even though `cd` **can** deal with unquoted spaces, it does not always work well with them. Plus, when calling programs with spaces in their paths you **will** have issues with unquoted spaces. My recommendation is to use a consistently reliable method in both path and program "situations" which means using double quotes around paths/programs with spaces.